# how to check if an addressable asset or scene is cached after been downloaded in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using addressable assets to remote download a new scene from server, What I'm trying to do is to activate a play button if the addressable scene is already downloaded and in cache, and a download button if it is not in cache so that the player won't download the addressable from server every time he wants to play the scene.

I tried using Caching. `IsVersionCached` to check the bundle is in the cache using the bundle name but the problem here is that the name is not a good reference since in the addressable system I load the scene using Addressable. `loadscene` which loads the scene directly without giving any reference to the asset bundle. so the question is how to check if the scene is cached?
Here is what I tried with but it is not working since I already know that the asset bundle name won't be the good reference at least in this example.

```
private IEnumerator LoadRoutine()
    {



        var lastHash = PlayerPrefs.GetString(LAST_HASH);

        if (Caching.IsVersionCached(AssetBundleHavingTheScene.name, Hash128.Parse(lastHash)))
        {

            Debug.Log("The Bundle is Cached i'll launch it");

            Addressables.LoadScene(AddressableScene);


        }


        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Cached I'm going to download it");




            var async = Addressables.LoadScene(AddressableScene);


            while (!async.IsDone)
            {

                ProgressNumber.text = (async.PercentComplete * 100f).ToString("F0") + ("%");
                ProgressSlider.value = async.PercentComplete;

                Debug.Log(async.PercentComplete);
                yield return null;
            }

            // At this point the scene is loaded and referenced in async.Result
            Debug.Log("LOADED!");

            Scene myScene = async.Result;




        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I  know, Addressable assets are automatically cached by unity and will not be downloaded twice. But you have to make sure that when you build the addressables in the unity editor, you select 'update existing build' (or similar) rather than a clean build. 
But if you still want to check manually, you could use the method "Addressables.GetDownloadSizeAsync()". (Please read more about it in unity docs).

I hope it helps you a little bit.